# Copying attribute table definition to one SHP to another using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, 3d

I have a SHP with 3D vectors and in the other hand, a SHP with attribute table definition. I need one SHP with the 3D vectors and the attribute table definition.

It's important to understand that the attribute table is empty. That's actually my job to fill it.

I tried to copy/paste the 3D vectors to a SHP to the other with attribute table definition but I noticed that Z information get lost.

So I have two solution:

- find out a solution to copy/paste the vectors without losing the z coordinate
- find out a solution to import the empty attribute table definition into the shp containing the vectors.

Comment: What is your vector type? Points, lines, polygons...?

Comment: How do you know which shape and which table row belong together?

Comment: This are points or lines.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of your question it sounds like you need to join two tables together dependent on a common feature (i.e. rowID). Try using the Spatial Query plugin. Go to  Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins... and search for 'Spatial Query Plugin' install that, if you haven't got it installed already.
Once Installed go to Vector > Spatial Query > Spatial Query follow the dialogue box which is pretty intuitive and it will create a new vector for you with the attributes joined for you.

Comment: Do you think that z coordinate will be included in the new vector? Because basically in QGIS when you edit vectors z coordinate disappear.